# Python hex string operation: need to preserve the leading zeros

Tags: python, string, hex

I have two numbers:

a = "00000108"

b = "FFFFF9FF"

I want to compute the bitwise AND of the hex values in the two strings. The result I want is a string:
"00000108"

Here is what I have come up with:

```
def fixedAND(a, b):
    '''
    The a and b are both strings
    '''
    return ''.join([hex(ord(i) & ord(j))[2:] for i,j in zip(a.decode('hex'), b.decode('hex'))])
```

This function returns "0018". It suppresses the leading zeros for each of the two hex digit pairs.

Comment: @linuxfan, can you put this as the answer? I will take this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to convert your strings to integers, perform the AND and later print the result in a format of your choice. For e.g

```
>>> a = "00000108"
>>> b = "FFFFF9FF"
>>> format(int(a, 16) & int(b, 16), '08x')
'00000108'
```